# Missing value when summing in awk

Tags: awk

I have two-column files, with first column sorted, such that

```
0 107
1 1
1 141
2 22
3 1
3 222
4 65
5 1
5 53
6 79
```

I want an output with no repeated entries in the first column, and as the second column the sum of the second-column old values of the repeated first-column values. My attempt: `awk '$1 != p{ if (NR>1) print p, s; p=$1; s=0} {s+=$2} END{print p, s}'`, which outputs

```
 107
1 142
2 22
3 223
4 65
5 54
6 79
```

That is, the `0` value in the first column of the first row is not displayed. What am I missing? One-liner solution preferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I recommend to enclose the if-clause action in brackets. For example, below it is clear that the if-clause only applies to `{print p,s}`, and not to `p=$1` and `s=0`:

```
awk '$1!=p{if(NR>1){print p,s};p=$1;s=0}{s+=$2}END{print p,s}'
```

That is cosmetic, though, but not a mistake.

Your mistake consists in not noticing that **unset variables are treated both as `0` and the null string in comparisons**. For the first line of the file, `$1=0`. Therefore, `$1!=p` is **false** for the first line (since `p` is unset), which means that `p` is still not set when awk starts reading the second line.

A possible solution is to set `p` to the null string at the program start:

```
awk 'BEGIN{p=""}$1!=p{if(NR>1){print p,s};p=$1;s=0}{s+=$2}END{print p,s}' file
```

```
awk '$1!=p{if(NR>1){print p,s};p=$1;s=0}{s+=$2}END{print p,s}' p="" file
```

Now, the `$1!=p` comparison is **true** for the first line, as `0!=""`.

Output:

```
0 107
1 142
2 22
3 223
4 65
5 54
6 79
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
awk '$1 != p && NR>1{print p, s; s=0} {p=$1; s+=$2} END{print p, s}'
```

#### How it works

Any time that we come to the end of sequence, `$1 != p && NR>1`, we print `p, s` and reset `s` back to zero.

For every line, we set `p` to the first column and we increment `s` by the second column.

After the last line, we print `p, s`.

Comment: Thanks! It works like a charm, but I've accepted Quasimodo's answer because it explains where I was failing.